# Android Studio 3.0.1, Change Code Color

Tags: android, colors, edit, android-studio-3.0

After updating Android Studio to 3.0.1 in iMac, the Edit window color changed to white in the Edit window. Tell me how to change the color of the code.

I want to know how to do that. I'd appreciate it if you knew someone you knew.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUlII.png]

R.layout.activity_main <- White Color

Thank.

The problem has been resolved by turning the issue off(Power Save Mode Option).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV1Er.png)

Comment: If you resolved the problem yourself, please write the solution as an answer below and mark the answer as accepted instead of editing the answer into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this .

Open the Android Studio

```
File 
-> Settings 
-> Colors&Fonts 
-> Java(XML)
-> change foreground you want on the right- top whee I tag.
```

if you want change XML code color , you can find XML to change .

**Or**

You can import sublime color

https://github.com/OtaK/jetbrains-monokai-sublime

You can download jar.

Then use this

```
File
-> Import Settings
-> Find your jar ,and use it
```

[image]